# python cannot import opencv because it can't find libjpeg.8.dylib

Tags: python, macos, opencv, jpeg

Trying to get opencv for python working on Mac OSX - Mavericks but keep getting an image not found for libjpeg.8.dylib when doing import cv from python

(Recently updated from Mountain Lion)

This is what I did:

1.`brew tap homebrew/science`

2.`brew install opencv`

3.`python`

4.`import cv`

### -got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

---

5. I looked for libjpeg.8.dylib and found it in `/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/` which, apparently, is not where libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib is looking.

I'm a bit new to Mac OS and homebrew. Could anyone explain how to resolve this error and get opencv running? I have the python that comes preinstalled with Mac and them python installed by homebrew.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

The quick and dirty solution for this is to make a symlink inside of the /usr/local/lib folder pointing to the actual location of libjpeg.8.dylib, like this:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
```

The problem is opencv and python expect libjpeg.8.dylib to be in /usr/local/lib/ but homebrew installs it in /usr/local/Cellar/, hence annoying error.

Comment: This is working. Is there any "better" solution ? by better I mean something that is not dirty.

Comment: You could try modifying python's search path [like this](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#inst-search-path) and doing   `import sys`  `sys.path.append('/usr/local/Cellar/')`

Comment: Thank you!  Google was failing me until I saw this answer.

Comment: godddd why is opensource software always like this. Always, not a single time things work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

I used brew a for installing OpenCV on my mac, and ran into this same problem, but it was with an Xcode C++ console application.

However an alternative method to solve the problem is to copy `cp` the file to the library location.

```
cp /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
```

Or the latter, which I don't suggest, just stating another method is to use move `mv` the entire file location into your /usr/local/lib/ directory.

```
mv /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Answer (score 3):

Just had a similar problem to this (in python `import opencv` was working for me one day, then the next it threw the same error you are reporting) and this solution just worked for me:

Upgrade your homebrew opencv eg.:

`brew upgrade opencv` (or in my case `brew upgrade opencv3`)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Pillow library on macOS. [The solution proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728960/install-libjpeg-v8-to-opt-local) to install it from source worked for me. I had to install it to `/usr/local/` for Pillow to find it. You'll need command-line tools, which is the purpose of the first line:

```
xcode-select --install
curl -O -J -L http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8.tar.gz
tar xvfz jpeg*tar.gz                 # Unzip and untar what you downloaded
cd jpeg-8                            # Change directory to wherever it unpacked to
./configure --prefix="/usr/local"    # Configure with the necessary prefix
make
sudo make install
```