# Error importing pyhdf module in Python

Tags: python, pyhdf

I have followed the instructions from http://hdfeos.org/software/pyhdf.php detailing how to install pyhdf and subsequently attempted to run the example code listed on this site (found [here](http://hdfeos.org/examples/code/pyhdf/AIRS.py.txt)). Unfortunately, when I run the example code (which I saved as hdf.py) I get the following error message:

```
$python hdf.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hdf.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC
  File "/Users/kyleniezgoda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhdf-0.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pyhdf/SD.py", line 1004, in <module>
    from . import hdfext as _C
  File "/Users/kyleniezgoda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhdf-0.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pyhdf/hdfext.py", line 28, in <module>
    _hdfext = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/kyleniezgoda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhdf-0.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pyhdf/hdfext.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
  _mod = imp.load_module('_hdfext', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kyleniezgoda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhdf-0.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pyhdf/_hdfext.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/kyleniezgoda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhdf-0.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pyhdf/_hdfext.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Anyone see something similar to this or have any suggestions? I am running on Mac OS 10.10.3 Yosemite, if that helps.

Comment: Looks like the `libjpeg.8.dylib` library could not be found. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187742/python-cannot-import-opencv-because-it-cant-find-libjpeg-8-dylib) helps?

Comment: I viewed that page before posting this, and the suggestions did not work. 'libjpeg.8.dylib' is already in my /usr/local/lib/ which is part of my Python path, and so Python should not have a problem finding the file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem by upgrading numpy version. You can type following words in Anaconda Prompt:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

and then import it again.

Comment: This worked for me.  Python 3.8.2, pyhdf 0.10.5 and numpy 1.21.4.  It upgraded to the same version of numpy but it still fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install jpeg with this command in Anaconda prompt:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jpeg
```