# Unable to import cv2 in python2.7 on OSX El Capitan (opencv3.1.0)

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, importerror, osx-elcapitan

I have used this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) to install opencv on my mac (without virtual environment). However, when I run python and want to import cv2, I get the following error:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 1, in
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_reg.3.1.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
Reason: image not found
```

I've tried the solution stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187742/python-cannot-import-opencv-because-it-cant-find-libjpeg-8-dylib), but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since I couldn't find a practical solution, I eventually ended up installing the virtual environment, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was fixed by specifying the path to the opencv library:

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/full/path/to/opencv/build/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`