# libjpeg.8.dylib can't be loaded when using Python tool

Tags: python, shared-libraries, hdf

I have faild to run a tool using for satellite data process [CCPLOT](http://ccplot.org/)

After successfully installed, I tried the first case.

Here is the error information.

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/Users/HYF/anaconda/bin/ccplot", line 56, in <module>      
>from ccplot.hdf import HDF    
>ImportError: dlopen(/Users/HYF/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccplot/hdf.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib      
>Referenced from: /Users/HYF/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccplot/hdf.so
```

I have look through this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187742/python-cannot-import-opencv-because-it-cant-find-libjpeg-8-dylib)

I have tried `sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib`.

And now the **libjpeg.8.dylib** are stay in the folder /usr/local/lib/

But the error doesn't disappear. How to fix this bug?

I'm using Mac OS X system with Anaconda installed.
Any advice would be appreciate!

#### PS

Thanks for the advice.

with `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib python`

The error is the same
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/HYF/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccplot/hdf.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/HYF/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccplot/hdf.so
  Reason: image not found

With `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib python`.

`from ccplot.hdf import HDF` shows no errors.

But when I import matplotlib, there is another error shows

> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/HYF/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
>     Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
>    in /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib

Comment: Try `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib python` just in case `/usr/local/lib` is not on your path.  Try `otool -L /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib` to make sure its dependencies are satisfied.  Try `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib python` so that the jpeg library is preloaded.  These aren't good long term solutions, but they may help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using otool tool, this is the output:    `/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib:
 /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)`

Comment: Is the version 1213.00 un-suitable for the system?

Comment: Anaconda has matplotlib available: use `conda install matplotlib` to install.  You should be using [environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) so it is easier to clean up if you make a mistake installing something.

Comment: Looking at your matplotlib import error, it is picking up `/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib`.  If you had install matplotlib via anaconda, it is probably linked against `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib` (`otool -L` will tell you), and the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is causing it to load the  wrong directory.  Maybe `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`?  See `man dyld` for details.